# NodeJS does not returning status code but changes database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my code below works just fine and updates or creates documents, but does not return status code 200 it just waits without any return value, any idea why this is happening

```
  exports.flagUser = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const user = await FlaggedUser.findOne({ userId: req.body.userId });
    
        if (user) {
          if (user.flaggedBy.includes(req.body.flaggedBy.toString())) {
            print("error");
            return res.status(500);
          } else {
            console.log("user found");
            await user.updateOne({
              $inc: { flagCount: 1 },
              $addToSet: { flaggedBy: req.body.flaggedBy },
            });
            return res.status(200);
          }
        } else {
          const flaggedUser = new FlaggedUser({
            _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            userId: req.body.userId,
            flagCount: 1,
            flaggedBy: [req.body.flaggedBy],
          });
          await flaggedUser.save();
          console.log("flag");
          return res.status(200);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json({
          ...error,
        });
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send just status codes you need to write `res.status(num).send();` or `res.status(num).end();`. Here is the doc to read more up on this http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: i want to return value to execute another code in frontent

Comment: Yea... if you want to return a status code you need to `.send()` otherwise express doesn't respond to the request

Comment: I believe you may also be able to do `res.status(num).end()`. Here is doc http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end. Eitherway you need to send back a response, and `.status()` is used to set the response status but not respond

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked... but have one more question then, i can get statusCode 500 in   print("error");
            return res.status(500); here without send how its happening

Comment: `.json()` is also another function used to send a response. It can get confusing at times,  but if you check out the docs and search up those functions the first sentence typically says something along the lines of `Sends a response`